# What is the new syntax of flops(0) and qp() in Matlab 2014?

Tags: matlab, syntax, syntax-error

I am running an old Matlab code, i.e., Version 5, and it seems some of the syntaxes have been changed in the newer versions of Matlab. I have Matlab 2014 and Want to know what is the new syntax for the code`flaps`.
First I have some problems about `flaps` command which seems to be removed from newer version. So what I have as a code about it is bellow, Just the necessary parts are posted, Please tell me how can I modify it for running on new matlab.

```
flops(0)      % and few lines after 
initial_flops = flops;
Flop = [Flop, flops];
fprintf(' Number of flops in     initial calculations: %i\n\n',initial_flops); 
disp('   beta        #flops(in K)     ')
disp(Flop_report)
net_flops
```

Also, I would like to know is `qp()` an old function in Matlab 5?
 If yes what is its alternative in New versions of Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

The function no longer exists, to benchmark code use `timeit` or `profile`.

Comment: See also the [Lightspeed toolbox](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/software/lightspeed/).

Comment: This is not a compelet answer to the question above @Daniel

Comment: @Electricman: This is an answer to the original question before it was edited.

Comment: That's true @Daniel But he modified his question to ask for more information.